# conditional variable definition based on a popped value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following javascript two variables are being set by checked radio_button values.

However, there is an edge case that is not handled. Where the last character of
`$("input[name=Arm]:checked").val();`  is zero, for example: `471_SAN_0`
then, var Armpad_image should also be `0`.  How can this be best handled?

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  var Arm_image = $("input[name=Frame]:checked").val() + '_' + $("input[name=Arm]:checked").val();
  $("#Arm").attr("src", "/Arm_" + Arm_image + ".png");
  console.log(Arm_image);
  console.log("#Arm");
  var Armpad_image = $("input[name=Armpad]:checked").val();
  $("#Armpad").attr("src", "/Armpad_" + Armpad_image + ".png");
  console.log(Armpad_image);
  console.log("#Armpad");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><div class='row'>
              <input type="radio" id="SAN_0" name="Arm" value="0" >
              None
          </div></label>
<label><div class='row'>
              <input type="radio" id="SAN_F" name="Arm" value="F" checked="checked">
              Fixed
          </div></label>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML

Comment: Seems a simple `if` should solve this. And do you mean Arm_image or Armpad_image?

Comment: @mplungjan Updated.  it is the value of `input[name=Arm]:checked`  whence popped of all characters (in the snippet, there is only 1 character, but there can be many), save the last one is = 0, that Armpad_image should also = 0

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a div in a label

Comment: Also you did not post `frame` - anyway see my answer

Comment: Why not just get the last character using charAt ($("input[name=Armpad]:checked").val().length-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a var

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  var armVal = $("input[name=Arm]:checked").val() || "";
  var Arm_image = $("input[name=Frame]:checked").val() + '_' + armVal;
  $("#Arm").attr("src", "/Arm_" + Arm_image + ".png");
  console.log(Arm_image);
  var Armpad_image = armVal.length && armVal.slice(-1) == 0 ? 0 : $("input[name=Armpad]:checked").val();
  $("#Armpad").attr("src", "/Armpad_" + Armpad_image + ".png");
  console.log(Armpad_image);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label><div class='row'>
              <input type="radio" id="SAN_0" name="Arm" value="0" >
              None
          </div></label>
<label><div class='row'>
              <input type="radio" id="SAN_F" name="Arm" value="F" checked="checked">
              Fixed
          </div></label>
```

Comment: I had to invoke the input value, as armVal was undefined.  `var Armpad_image = $("input[name=Arm]:checked").val() == 0 ? 0 : $("input[name=Armpad]:checked").val();`